# Route login not defined [InvalidArgumentException]

Tags: laravel

Need your help about the issue , can't understand what the problem is ?

The get router is for getting the login page .. 
The post router for the login to the system ..

```
Route::post('/logger',['as' => 'logger','uses' => 'LoginController@login']);

Route::get('/login', function() {
return view('login');
});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the route properly, outside of closure

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
     return view('login');
})->name('login'); //name() is in here
```

Comment: I have the following problem when doing that , i added above .

Comment: look again plz, name is outside of closure